# A string such as "hello" is really a static array of individual characters in C

Tags: c

How a string is a static array in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void array();

int main() {
    printf("first turn");
    array();
    array();
    return 0;
}

void array() {
    char a[] = "hello";
    printf("this is at first call%c", a[1]);
    a[1] = 'z';
}
```

In both calls to `array()` the output is the same, so how we can call a string as a static array?

Comment: `a` clearly is *not* defined `static`.

Comment: *is really a static array* Not really, you misunderstand.

Comment: A string such as “hello” is really a static array of individual characters in C
 is this statement true or false??? i read this in a book and i want to know how this can be true .

Comment: Although `a`'s *initialiser* `"hello"` is static, as it's a sting literal.

Comment: @DeiDei: `"hello"` is a string literal. A string literal has static storage duration.

Comment: alk can you check dietel and dietel c how to program chapter 6 arrays page 237 point number 2 .i know properly the difference between storage classes static and automatic .but that point is a bit confusing for me. thankyou for giving your time.

Comment: @Abhishekmehra: I do not object your statement. I checked the C Standard [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6). Still `a` and `"hello"` are *two different* things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text you're quoting is talking about a string literal, such as the argument to `printf()` here:

```
printf("hello");
```

or the string that's used to initialize a pointer variable:

```
char *p = "hello";
```

In your code, you're declaring a local array, and the string literal is being used to initialize it. Your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
char a[6];
strcpy(a, "hello");
```

The second argument to `strcpy()` would be allocated statically, but `a` is local to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to declare your variable with the static keyword:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 void array();

 int main(){
     printf("first turn");
     array();
     array();
     return 0;
 }

void array(){
    static char a[]="hello";
    printf("this is at first call %c\n",a[1]);
    a[1]='z';
 }
```

Comment: "how we can call a string as a static array?" Is this the question ?

Answer (score 0):

*In both calls to array() the output is the same ?*  `a` is created both the times when you called `array()` because it's locally created `stack` variable. It's scope is function-scope. It's gets destroyed once control goes out of `array()` function.

Here

`char a[]="hello";`

`a` is not a *static array*, it's a *stack created local array*. Variable `a` resides in `stack` section of the primary memory RAM. Note that here string literal `hello` also stored in `stack` section.

This

`static char a[]="hello";`

is called `static` array. Here `a` scope is file scope.

Answer (score 0):

The function `array()` does not modify or print `"hello"`, but `a` which got *initialised* using "hello". This initialisation happens again each time `array()` is called.